# How to prevent spawning of unnecessary worker threads for views that are already been recycled?

Tags: android, multithreading, scala, asynchronous, future

I implemented a simple `ListActivity` with a custom `ArrayAdapter`. The layout contains an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. In the custom adapter's `getView` method I start a **future** to download the image concurrently at the desired position. Now, when I quickly scroll the list, the app will crash because it spawns too many download worker threads and will eventually ran out of memory.

Almost all triggered worker threads will download the image only to discard it again because the `ImageView` for which it was triggered will have been reused by that time, and only a few (the items to fill the full height of the device screen) are ever visible at once.

Is there a pattern to circumvent the behavior?

How about:

- Custom thread pool
- Override some of Android's lifecycle methods
- LRU-Cache

What is the best practice to prevent the app from spawning too many unnecessary threads?

Answer (score 1):

Don't spawn threads in getView-  at the very least don't do one per bind.  Usually you'd use a networking library such as Volley, RetroFit, etc that handles it for you.  But if you want to do it yourself, go with either one download thread or a small thread pool and post requests to it.  Make sure you include cancel functionality, and cancel requests that are no longer valid because they've been scrolled out of screen.

But really, just use a library that already has all of this written for you.

Comment: How to prevent one per bind? Small thread pool and post requests to it? How am I doing this? I'm new to Android and I wanted to start with the basics to get a better understanding. Then I would move on to using external libs etc. What's the preferred location of spawning these threads then? In the `Activity`s onCreate?

Comment: The problem isn't really whee you're doing it, so much as the frequency.  Get view is called all the time. If you spawn a thread every call, you can have hundreds of threads. Instead, either the activity of the adapter should had a single thread or a thread pool that does all of the networking, with a request queue. Even using AyncTask would be better, as they're actually executed serially on one thread- you may eventually overload things, but it won't spawn dozens of workers.